# Why am I getting error when using Structs and Enums in Function?

Tags: c

I am trying to pass two `enums` and one `struct` to a `funtion`. But the program always stops and returns error.

Enums and Struct:

```
typedef enum GameMode
{
    easy_mode = 10,
    medium_mode = 20,
    hard_mode = 30
} GameMode;

typedef enum Field
{
    small_field = 7,
    medium_field = 15,
    big_field = 30
} Field;

typedef struct Game
{
    int x;
    int y;
    GameMode mode;
    Field field;
} Game;
```

The way I am trying to call the `funtion` (shown below): `new_game(game, mode, field);`. The `game` init looks like this: `Game *game;`. 100% that the `mode` and `field` parameters are passing right values (printed them out in the function).

And this is the function:

```
void new_game(Game *game, GameMode mode, Field field)
{
    game->mode = mode;
    game->field = field;

    game->x = game->field;
    game->y = game->field;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"stops and returns error"*? Please provide a full [mcve] and explain the problem in more detail

Comment: `Game *game;` is not init but just an declaration with no initialization. You must pass right value to also `game`, not only `mode` and `field`.

Comment: Which error do you get when you do what?

Comment: How did you declared and initaliazed mode and field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to structs or enums being used in functions.

I suppose you do this:

```
void new_game(Game *game, GameMode mode, Field field)
{
    game->mode = mode;      // if game point nowhere, this will most likely crash
    game->field = field;    // your program

    game->x = game->field;
    game->y = game->field;
}
...
Game *game;                   // here game is not initialized, it points nowhere
new_game(game, mode, field);
```

You probably want this:

```
Game game;                    // here game is a Game, not a pointer to Game like above
new_game(&game, mode, field); // pass the pointer to game
```